# Adding file upload to SlickGrid cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

On the slickgrid view I have to add the  button to do file upload. I have added that button using a custom formater. But I couldnt add the onchange event handler to capture the file. Could anyone have any idea of how we can add the onchange listener to the cell.?

Comment: `grid.onCellChange.subscribe(function(e, args){...});`

Answer (score 0):

In the formatter display just the name of the file or something like that. To achieve your goal you need to write custom editor which implements isValueChanged method. You can modify this or any other editor taken from:

https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.editors.js

```
      function myCustomEditor(args) {
        var $input;
        var defaultValue;
        var scope = this;

        this.init = function () {
          $input = $("<INPUT type=text class='editor-text' />")
              .appendTo(args.container)
              .bind("keydown.nav", function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.LEFT || e.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.RIGHT) {
                  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                }
              })
              .focus()
              .select();
        };

        this.destroy = function () {
          $input.remove();
        };

        this.focus = function () {
          $input.focus();
        };

        this.getValue = function () {
          return $input.val();
        };

        this.setValue = function (val) {
          $input.val(val);
        };

        this.loadValue = function (item) {
          defaultValue = item[args.column.field] || "";
          $input.val(defaultValue);
          $input[0].defaultValue = defaultValue;
          $input.select();
        };

        this.serializeValue = function () {
          return $input.val();
        };

        this.applyValue = function (item, state) {
          item[args.column.field] = state;
        };

        this.isValueChanged = function () {
          return (!($input.val() == "" && defaultValue == null)) && ($input.val() != defaultValue);
        };

        this.validate = function () {
          if (args.column.validator) {
            var validationResults = args.column.validator($input.val());
            if (!validationResults.valid) {
              return validationResults;
            }
          }

          return {
            valid: true,
            msg: null
          };
        };

        this.init();
      }
```

the editor can be then assigned in your columns object:

```
    var columns = [

      {id: "title", name: "Title", field: "title", width: 70, minWidth: 50, cssClass: "cell-title", sortable: true, editor: myCustomEditor},

    ];
```